# Gradle compile error "No Signature of Method"

Tags: android, gradle, android-build, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to run ./gradlew build.gradle from terminal, I have been getting following error:

```
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated) values: [project ':TestMobile']
Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
```

I have tried applying java plugin at root build.gradle file and also on sub projects. but still I get same error.

I have the following project structure:

```
ProjectRepos
->build.gradle
->settings.gradle
->TestMobile (Android plugin)
   ->build.gradle
->ThirdParty/SlidingMenu (Android library)
  ->build.gradle
```

Where top level build.gradle contains:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-   projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    compile project(':TestMobile')
    compile project(':ThirdParty:SlidingMenu')      
}
}
```

settings.gradle contains following:

```
include ':ThirdParty:SlidingMenu'
include ':TestMobile'
```

TestMobile -> build.gradle contains following:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':ThirdParty:SlidingMenu')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
 }
}
```

ThirdParty/SlidingMenu -> build.gradle contains following:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 18
buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

sourceSets {
    main {
        ......
        ......

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 15):

You can't have `compile` dependencies in the `buildscript` block, only `classpath` dependencies. Also you can't have project dependencies there. You probably just need to get rid of these two lines.

Comment: If I remove those lines and keep only class path. I get following error : FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'build.gradle' not found in root project 'ProjectRepos'.

Comment: This means that you got past the earlier problem. You need to call `./gradlew build`, not `./gradlew build.gradle`. I recommend to study the first few chapters of the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), which will make you more successful with Gradle.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me realise I have to add my Guava, Gson, etc dependencies in a top level `dependencies` block. (Then, in Android Studio, run "Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle files" to make the libs available in the IDE.)

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was a simple syntax error (missing commas) when adding a string resource:

Incorrect:

```
resValue "string" "app_name" "My App Dev"
```

Correct:

```
resValue "string", "app_name", "My App Dev"
```